# java.net.URISyntax Exxception : illegal character in query at index 75

Tags: php, android

i am trying to send multiple parameters from my android concatenating in a string comma separated which include useId,date and time, other details i am facing froblem in receiving those parameters to server.

my url generates as follows--->

```
tempuri/add_ER_Record.php?param=73,ACQ000000005,5,**10-Dec-13 10:20:00 PM**,12,2013,pune,A410,Accomodation,500,black,y,picture
```

when hit in browser it works but through android it shows exception at index 75 and that is my date and time parameter.

Comment: URLEncode your String and it should be through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String x = "add_ER_Record.php?param=73,ACQ000000005,5,**10-Dec-13 10:20:00 PM**,12,2013,pune,A410,Accomodation,500,black,y,picture";
String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(x,"UTF-8");
```

should do

Comment: i modified my code and encoded url by URLEncoder.encode(url);